# Schedule tasks at fixed time in multiple timezones

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm getting started with Airflow and I'm not sure how to approach this problem:

I'm building a data export system that should run at a fixed time daily for different locations. My issue is that the locations have several timezones and the definition of day start/end changes depending on the timezone.

I saw in the documentation that I can make a dag timezone aware but I'm not sure creating 100s of dags with different timezone is the right approach. I also have some common tasks so multiple dags creates more complexity or duplication in the tasks performed.

Is there an airflow idiomatic way to achieve this? I think it would be a fairly common use case to build reports that are timezone dependant but I didn't find any informations about it.

Comment: How many DAGs do you need (of the same type) at a fixed time? Do they vary in other way? Like service they consume or something else.

Comment: The dags are quite similar, arguments and some branches in the code are the only difference.


I have ~800 different locations distributed in 64 uniques timezones so that would be 64 dags doing pretty much the same thing at different time of the day

Comment: Well, there are only 24 timezones in the world, so I assume you can join some of them. I'll elaborate a bit in the answer.

Comment: Yeah I can limit it to 24 1h slots but then it doesn't work with the daylight savings! Some timezone with the same utc offset don't have the same daylight saving offset or they don't switch at the same time.

My "good enough" solution right now is running a dag every hour and check for which timezone it's midnight and bypass the other timezones's tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic DAGs is a hot topic in Airflow, but from my point of view, Airflow itself doesn't provide a straightforward way to implement that. You'll need to balance the pros and cons depending on your use case.

As a good starting point, you can check [Astronomer guide for dynamically generating DAGs](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags). There you have all the options available and some ideas of the pros and cons. Make sure you check out the [scalability considerations](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags#scalability) to see the implications in terms of performance.

From your use case, I think the best approach will be either the *Create_DAG Method* (under [Single-File Methods](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags#single-file-methods)), or the [*DAG Factory*](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags#dag-factory). I personally prefer the first one because it's like a Factory (in terms of programming patterns), but you have the flexibility to create all the files you need for each DAG. In the second you won't have much control of what you create and there's an external dependency needed.

Another interesting article about dynamically generating DAGs is ["How to build a DAG Factory on Airflow"](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-dag-factory-on-airflow-9a19ab84084c).